# OpenSSL OCSP Responder "Cert Status: good" -> "Cert Status: unknown"

Tags: certificates, openssl, certificate-revocation, ocsp

**Summary:**

Certificates calling to OCSP Responder (OCSPr) have their "Cert Status" change from "good" to "unknown" with no known to changes to environment. Completely lost on this one.

**More Detail:**

I have been building a simple suite for Certificate creation and OCSP handling for local and personal certificate testing and the such. Everything has been going well, and there hasn't been any issues with the generated certs checking against the OCSPr until the past few weeks.

I have generated a variety of Server and Client Certs and spread them around to various sites for testing and they function properly except for the following:

I have generated two Server Certs and two Client Certs and placed them on their respective sites, and initially these Certs call in to the OCSPr with a Cert Status of "unknown" for a few minutes, then switch to "good" for an undetermined amount of time, and then back to "unknown" until the OCSPr and the web site are both reset, and then the cycle repeats itself.

The other Client and Server certificates that have been created and placed on other sites are still functioning properly and communicate immediately and with ease with the OCSPr.

**Some Info that May be Useful:**

OpenSSL Version: `OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019`

The environment is setup such as: `CA -> InterCA -> Device/Server/OCSP Certificates`

The OCSP Responder looks like:

```
sudo openssl ocsp 
-url http://ocsp.address.com -port 80
-index Inter_index.txt 
-CA certs/InterCA.cert.pem 
-rkey private/ocsp.key.pem 
-rsigner certs/ocsp.cert.pem 
-out ocsp_log.txt 
-text -rm sha384 -ignore_err
```

I've also substituted `-CA certs/InterCA.cert.pem` with `-CA certs/ca_chain.cert.pem` with similar results (I heard that OpenSSl doesn't care for CA chains, but no harm in trying)

I'm sure there is more I could add to this that would be helpful, but nothing comes to mind at the moment. :-)

**[ UPDATE ]**

I was able to get into the server logs of the site that the Client Side is attempting to communicate with. After watching the logs, I noticed a pattern;

Whenever the Client is speaking with the Server without issues, this output is logged:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.592 - Accepted connection from [IP_Address]:[Port] on local port [port]
[AsumCallHome] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.798 - Checking for commands to process
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.959 - SQL Total Query: select count(*) from AsumClient
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.959 - SQL Query: from AsumClient order by lastPing desc, uid asc
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.960 - Total = 3
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.962 - OpenFiles: AsumHome.getClientsWithStatus diff: 0 Total= 0
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-1] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.981 - SQL Total Query: select count(*) from AsumClientGroup
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-1] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.982 - SQL Query: from AsumClientGroup order by name asc
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-1] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:08.982 - OpenFiles: AsumHome.getClientGroups diff: 0 Total= 0
[pool-1-thread-125] 08 Dec 2020 21:37:09.103 - IOException: closing Connection from [IP_Address]:[Port], will no longer read messages with this Receiver.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read timed out
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:137)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:716)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:799)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.llp.MllpDecoderState.read(MllpDecoderState.java:128)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.llp.MllpDecoder.getMessage(MllpDecoder.java:63)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.llp.Hl7DecoderReader.getMessage(Hl7DecoderReader.java:84)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.llp.MinLLPReader.getMessage(MinLLPReader.java:33)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.Receiver.handle(Receiver.java:63)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service.run(Service.java:205)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
        ... 18 more
```

Whenever the Client is speaking with the Server with the issue mentioned, this output is logged:

```
[pool-1-thread-134] 08 Dec 2020 21:38:41.979 - SocketException on read() attempt.  Socket appears to have been closed: End of input stream reached before message starts
[pool-1-thread-134] 08 Dec 2020 21:38:41.979 - SocketException: closing Connection from [IP_Address]:[Port], will no longer read messages with this Receiver: End of input stream reached before message starts
```

I haven't gone any deeper than this yet though. Still attempting to understand what is happening here. Is this a Server side issue that is causing a lack of communication with the OCSPr? Or something with the OCSPr that is causing the Server end to fail here? I'm not sure yet.

Comment: `Unknown` implies the OCSP responder doesn't know anything about that cert. Wild guesses: could the index file be getting corrupted / write-locked by another process, or similar? Another wild guess: did the certs expire? That usually causes a cert to go from `Good` to `Unknown` when the OCSP server stops tracking it.

Comment: I follow where you are going with this train of thought, but if that were the case, could the index file uncorrupt or unwrite-lock itself when it saw fit? Maybe there is something blocking it for long periods of time, but I can't think of what that would be, and why only these certs. It gives me an idea, and I will look further into it. Thank you!

I've check the expiration dates, and those are good till a year from now, and all of the certs are labeled as V. I can also "confirm" the status of the Server/Client certs via the "openssl ocsp -issues etc..." command.

Comment: You've got a good puzzle here. I'll keep this tab open to see if anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: Tiny Updates: I've discovered that the only the website side of things need to be updated for the Certs to start being noticed again, and within 15 minutes, they return back to an "unknown" status. Also, occasionally the certs will return to "good," only to revert back to "unknown" in about 15 minutes. I'm thinking the issue relies on the website side, and I am soon to dive deeper.

Comment: Most interesting. Based on that update, I would wireshark between browser and server and see what cert the website is serving. Is the website for some reason swapping which cert it's serving? Or is there something weird with the cert chain? Or something weird with the cert chain (for example some OCSP responders can be configured to respond for multiple CAs, in which case they need to be told the EE serial number and the issuing CA, giving the EE serial number alone will result in Unknown). Maybe if the website stops serving the intermediate cert, maybe the OCSP responder can't find it.